# Syntax error near keyword FROM

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
var DatabaseConnection = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection);
connection.Open();

string queryString = "SELECT ProjectNumber, FROM [dbo.][PROJECTS];" ;
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);         

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        querytext.Text = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

I read about putting reserved words between brackets or double quotes, but in my case this would be nonsense.

Comment: Remove the comma before FROM.

Comment: @jarlh thanks, feeling stupid for not seeing that... but its still not working. Now it's telling me that dbo.PROJECTS is an invalid object name.

Comment: Square brackets... `[dbo].[PROJECTS]`...

Comment: Also, possibly an important detail. I'm using amazon rds, when using the tools -> database connection and trying to view a database diagram. I got the message that the sever could not be used because of a more recent version then 2012.

Comment: @Pim Don't piggyback questions.  That is totally unrelated to this question.  Ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax:

```
SELECT ProjectNumber FROM [dbo].[PROJECTS]
```

Notes:

- No comma before the `FROM`.
- No period in the square braces to separate the schema and table name
- No semi-colon at the end (I'm not sure if this makes a difference.

Given these names, you don't need the square braces at all:

```
SELECT ProjectNumber FROM dbo.PROJECTS
```

Personally, I think unnecessary use of escape characters just clutters up queries, making them hard to write and to read.

Comment: Unfortunately, SSMS auto query generation puts the square brackets in for you.  Annoying.

Answer (score -2):

You should remove the comma (`,`) and move the period (`.`)

**Before**

```
SELECT ProjectNumber, FROM [dbo.][PROJECTS];
                    ^          ^
```

**After**

```
SELECT ProjectNumber FROM [dbo].[PROJECTS];
```